# How do you add elements from one ArrayList to another?

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have one ArrayList of fruits which has the name of the fruit and what its predominant vitamin is:

```
ArrayList<Foods> fruit; 
public Fruit() {
  fruit = new ArrayList<Foods>();
  fruit.add(new Foods("Orange", "Vitamin C"));
}
```

etc..

I want to add all the fruits with vitamin C to another array list so I iterated over them using:

```
Iterator vitC = fruit.iterator();
    while (vitC.hasNext()) {
        if (vitC.next().contains("Vitamin C")) {
            vitCfruit.add(vitC.next());
        }
}
```

However this adds the next value, so if apple was after orange in the list it would add apple to the next ArrayList instead of orange.

Comment: You can't have an `ArrayList<String, String>`

Comment: Then store it into an intermediate variable...

Comment: Your collection looks more like Map than List.

Comment: Yeah, my bad I just realised I wrote out a HashMap instead of a list, I have a list in my code (not sure why I've messed it up here) but the issue of printing the wron element still stands

Comment: Then please update your question with proper code example. To do so use [edit] option - it us placed under your post.

Comment: Edited, sorry if I'm still missing anything important (I think the code that the error is in is up there correctly)

Comment: It is not up there correctly. ArrayList does not have an add method taking two strings. Object does not have a contains method.

Comment: Calling `vitC.next()` twice inside the loop will skip one element on each iteration. Introduce a temporary variable like `Fruit currentFruit = vitC.next();` and use it for subsequent processing. *Even better:* `for (Fruit currentFruit : fruit)`...

Answer (score 1):

I'll ignore the apparent error in the code. In order to work with the element on the list you should do the following:

```
Iterator vitC = fruit.iterator();
    while (vitC.hasNext()) {
        Foods x = vitC.next();
        if (x.contains("Vitamin C")) { // should look for a Foods object here!!!
            administrators.add(x);
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I see what your fix is but I now get an error of error: cannot find symbol
   if (temp.contains("vitamin C")) {

Comment: I used `x` as a variable name. If you use `temp` make sure to be consistent.

Comment: I've got everything as temp, the full error is: error: cannot find symbol
   if (temp.contains("Vitamin C")) {
        ^
  symbol:   method contains(String)
  location: variable temp of type Foods

Comment: I think the problem is that you are using contains with a string when you should be using it with foods

Answer (score 0):

the vitC.next() in the 'if' you declared will work, but you will not be accessing the same element in the next line when add it to the new list.

use a tmp variable to store the vitC.next() and in case it match the condition you can still add ot..

```
Iterator vitC = fruit.iterator();
    while (vitC.hasNext()) {
        tmp = vitC.next();
        if (tmp.contains("Vitamin C")) { // should look for a Foods object here!!!
            administrators.add(tmp);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The enhanced for loop makes this straightforward:

```
for (Fruit thisFruit : fruit) {
    if (thisFruit.contains("Vitamin C")) {
        vitCfruit.add(thisFruit);
    }
}
```

In Java 8, this is simple with lambdas:

```
List<Foods> vitCfruit = fruit.stream()
    .filter(f -> f.contains("Vitamin C"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```